# JDBC PreparedStatement doesn't work but doesn't show any errors

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, debian, prepared-statement

i'm using a Tomcat 7 and i try to fill my MySQL Database with Java and JDBC. It worked with a small sample table(Tutorial link below) but now i try to fill my own values and it doesn't work anymore. Even the small example doesn't work. The weird thing is, i don't get any kind of errors or something. It just does nothing. I had to throw "errors" by myself to locate the problem. I think it's the PreparedStatement. Most of the time the last PreparedStatement.

I searched 2 days for a solution but without success. Maybe i forgot something or i deleted something while i was looking for the solution. I appriciate every kind of suggestions.

I used this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html and everything was fine. With my table and my insert code, it doesn't work.

Here is my code for the MySQL connection. That's everything inside the try part. I hope you find something or have some tips or something else.

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  //I tried the Connection with and without port. No difference
  connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?"
              + "user=ihaveanuser&password=ihaveapassword");
  statement = connect.createStatement();

  preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("insert into dbname.data values (default, ?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)");

  //These are just some random inserts based on the table. 
  //With the inserts i want to use it doesn't work neither.
  int tempint =  12345;
  double tempdouble = 12.12345;
  preparedStatement.setInt(1,tempint);
  preparedStatement.setInt(2,tempint);
  preparedStatement.setString(3,"test");
  preparedStatement.setInt(4, tempint);
  preparedStatement.setInt(5, tempint);
  preparedStatement.setString(6, "test");
  preparedStatement.setDouble(7, tempdouble);
  preparedStatement.setDouble(8, tempdouble);
  preparedStatement.setInt(9, tempint);
  preparedStatement.setString(10, "test");
  preparedStatement.setString(11, "test");

  preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Please don't hesitate to ask me questions.

Regards 
Eric

Comment: You are not setting parameter number 1, e.g ```preparedStatement.setString(1,"Test 1");```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I deleted it by accident. I do set this parameter in my code.

Comment: If you do not have autocommit and the storage engine behind the table is transactional, you need to add ```connect.commit()``` at the end.

Comment: ExecuteUpdate returns int - number if rows changed. Checking that you would give some insight.

Comment: Just revisited and counted ? - you have 10 ? but set 11 values...?